# Struck on shutdown page with logo

Tags: shutdown, freeze

I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu on my laptop. Although Windows 11 shuts down without any problem, when shutting down Ubuntu my laptop not power off after shutdown, instead it gets stuck at the manufacturer's logo screen.

[image]

Comment: We will need some more info. Please press Alt+Tab to see the output when shutting down, and update your post (press it before it gets stuck).